# UK Visitor visa refusal two times

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

My in laws parent got rejection two times on UK visitor visa. I want to know if we apply again so new visa application will be prepared or must be continuous from refusal letter,? Also is it necessary i have to mention about refusals.
Thank you so much
Kind regards 
Kaur

Comment: Please upload your refusal letter - without it we cannot help

Comment: You should mention the refusals. The UK authorities know your parents have been refused. If you fail to mention it they will refuse a visa on ground of deception, and probably impose a ban if you try again.

Comment: Two refusals means you might be making a fundamental error in the application and your next one might just be a waste of time and money unless you correct the error. As Coke said, upload your letter, with your personal details blanked out.